# Checking if string contains sentence with variable words

Tags: android, string, variables

It should be something like "Hello, my name is ??????????." in Open Office Base.

I am receiving a string from a website which is always build up like this:
"Hello, my name is " +name+ "."
The variable name can be ANY name with a length of up to 10 characters and it changes everyday.

I am trying to check if the string, that is provided by the website, contains this sentence (Example: "Hello, my name is John.").
BUT I don't know the name that the website provides, so I have to ask:

```
if(string1.contains("Hello, my name is " + ANY 10 CHARACTERS + "."))
{
return true;
}
```

Comment: whya not only writing string1.contains("Hans") for example? I think it will be better to show us some code. Where did You get the name? From en EditText?

Comment: if you already know the name why not just string1.contains("Hello, my name is " + mVar) ?

Comment: If your comaprison is strictly based on variable names. You need to rethink the code and implement a pattern.

Comment: try to  check <name> in string like string.contains("name");

Answer (score 3):

First need to parse out the name from the String by removing all characters besides the name.

```
String name = stringFromWebsite.replace("Hello, my name is ", ""); //remove "Hello, my name is "
name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1) //remove "." at the end
name = name.trim(); //trim any whitespaces
```

Next concatenate the base String + your variable.

```
String newString = "Hello, my name is " + name;
```

Now run the contains function against the new String

```
if (string1.contains(newString)){
     return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't provide the variable, the variable is provided by a website, that i download and is inside the string.

Comment: Be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Very hard to understand

Comment: I edited my post, I hope it is easier to understand now, my english is not very good.

Comment: I have updated my answer, your new edits made the question very clear :)